# gnome-terminal profile options

Tags: gnome-terminal

Does anybody know, what options are possible in a configuration file for gnome-terminal app?

I use the 2.31.3 version of gnome-terminal which is a part of RHEL 6 distribution.
I have tried to start gnome-terminal with --background option, but the following output has appeared:
Option "--background" is no longer supported in this version of gnome-terminal; you might want to create a profile with the desired setting, and use the new '--profile' option.

But I can't to know a markup for this file and possible options. There is no man page for gnome-terminal in RHEL 6. And I can't find it on GNOME web-site http://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/index.html.en

Comment: Sorry, I have forget to notice, my goal -- to start the gnome-terminal with specific colors from a bash script. GUI settings are useless for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and go to the file menu. There should be an option labeled "Profiles" under one of the menus.

You can change all sorts of settings including background/foreground colors and fonts. You can also create new profiles and store any number of different configurations within the interface.